# Where do I stop the thick traces?

Tags: pcb, design, routing

I am working on making a speed variator which also lets you invert the rotation of a motor. I have run into a few issues however. I don't know where to end the thick traces in my PCB design. This is my first big project so please don't mind my limited skills. Here the schematic of the PCB.

Feel free to ask me anything about the project and thank you in advance.

[image: Schematic]

[image: My attempt at routing]

Comment: You stop the thick traces when they no longer need to carry heavy current. Traces are the wires of a PCB and are sized based on current capacity and temperature.

Comment: Also be aware that you can make the tracks as wide as you like, you don’t pay for the extra copper.  If you’re going to etch this yourself then you’ll save on chemicals by leaving as much copper on the PCB as possible.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for routing almost all of your traces on the bottom layer? It's not like copper is cheaper on the bottom. Is this going to be a single-layer board with wires soldered in as jumpers?

Comment: The single-layer design is a bad idea. It can be made to work, but it won't look too much similar to what you've drawn.

Comment: EDIT; Yes, to clarify, this PCB is in fact one sided with the top layer being straps. Due to limitations in my country I can exclusively print single side boards.

Answer (score 1):

When the operating frequency is low (say, DC to 100 kHz) the thickness only significantly affects the trace resistance. You want to have thick traces *everyhwere* where a lot of current is expected. **Ideally, you would use polygons instead/on top of of traces to create the widest possible conductor on the PCB for high currents.** Also try to avoid making loops and sharp corners for high current tracks to prevent EMI. Loops can couple magnetically to whatever is inside the loop, while sharp corners can couple electrically outwards from the corner. But this is more of a pedantic note, usually it's not critical to functionality.

Polygons (when done properly) typically allow you to have both optimal current paths and eliminate sharp corners (depending on situation of course).

Look at your circuit and think about how the current travels to the load. Very high-current transients will usually come from a decouplig capacitor. Steady-state currents will come from the power supply into both load and decoupling. Therefore, (depending of course on how big the transients are expected to be) you want the thickest traces from decouplig cap to load. Similarly, you would want thick traces all the way from power supply to the decoupling and load. This applies to both power and ground.

Also keep in mind that vias can be a significant bottleneck. Wherever high currents cross layers, you want to have a grid of vias to ensure low resistance between the layers.